# Meaning of the support property in the definition of Bridgeland stability condition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, triangulated-categories, mirror-symmetry

Let $(Z,\mathcal{P})$ be a Bridgeland stability condition on a triangulated category $\mathcal{C}$. It is said to satisfy the support property if there exists a norm on $K(\mathcal{C})\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{R}$ and a constant $D$ such that
$$
||\gamma|| \le D|Z(\gamma)|
$$
for any semistable object $\gamma$. Here $K(\mathcal{C})$ is the numerical Grothandieck group of $\mathcal{C}$.

What is the geometric intuition behind this property (I heard it is related to special Lagrangian manifold on the mirror side)? How should one understand it?